# Aceessing Image from Sqlite Database

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I have a problem in my code that I am storing accessing the student data from sqlite database with student name, age and picture. I am storing all these data perfectly but cannot access the image field only.

Image shows blank on the screen,

I don't know why. Please Review my code and give me useful suggestions.

Thank You..

Here is Code:

```
package com.ex.imageStore;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewScreen extends Activity{
      SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newscreen);
        TextView name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView age = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        db = openOrCreateDatabase(
                "StudentData.db"
                , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY
                , null
                );

         db.setVersion(1);
            db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
            db.setLockingEnabled(true);

            Cursor cur = db.query("stuData", 
                    null, null, null, null, null, null);
                //cur.moveToFirst();
            cur.moveToPosition(0);
            name.setText(cur.getString(1));
            age.setText(cur.getString(2));
            byte[] bb = cur.getBlob(3);
 Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb,0,bb.length);
            img.setImageBitmap(theImage);//-->It //cannot convert bytearray to bitmap
               /* while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    tv.append("n" + cur.getString(1));
                    cur.moveToNext();
                }*/
                cur.close();


    }

}
```

theImage variable always assigned as null.........

Comment: How do you make sure that the image is getting saved in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `byte[] bb` to a `ByteArrayInputStream`. For your program, that would be

```
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bb);
Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
img.setImageBitmap(theImage);
```

I think this will help you.